# Mysql variable length decimal

Tags: mysql

I want to support 8.0, 8.22,8.333 ect using a decimal. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DECIMAL field has a fixed precision and can't be made to vary per-record. If you want variable precision, you'd need to use a FLOAT. Or you have a decimal field set to the highest required precision, and then use a second integer field to store how many digits that particular record should use.

Comment: Is float bad for use with calculations? I know that a double is bad.

Comment: Floats are a tool - it all comes down to how you use them. Using floats for currency is the major "no no"

Comment: This only works if you are getting ONE record at a time. If you'll be getting multiple rows and using another column variable for ROUND or TRUNCATE decimal length - it doesn't work.